# What is the difference between / Can I consolidate the local workspace $tf and $tf1 directories that TFS/VSO/Azure DevOps automatically generates?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have a local workspace that was created with **Visual Studio 2015** and **Visual Studio Online** ( now **Azure DevOps** ).

I have since installed **Visual Studio 2017** side-by-side.

In my *root* directory, I have two directories :

- **$tf**
- **$tf1** ( hidden )

I don't remember which was created first or what the difference is between the two. I was leaning towards one is for 2015 and one is for 2017, but it's simply a guess. Both directories are seemingly active, as they both have files/directories with current modification dates.

I am trying to figure out what the difference is between the two directories, why one is hidden and one is not, and/or if there is a way to consolidate them down into one directory.

Answer (score 0):

They should at least differ in the source control paths that they map. TFVC doesn't allow duplicate mapping as far as I know (just tried it on my machine). This might be an issue if you have a side by side installation because VS2015 ships with tf.exe version 14.xx and VS2017 comes with tf.exe version 15.xx, but I don't think so, in the past I've also used that combo and never encountered an issue.

You can check if both are really active and if/how they differ in terms of mapping by opening Source Control Explorer and selecting the Workspace dropdown -> Workspaces... -> Edit... -> Advanced >>

Here you can also change the mappings so that all what you want to get points to a single workspace and you can remove the other one if you don't want to keep it.

[image]

Comment: Well, it doesn't really make sense because I've only ever had a single workspace and it's at the root level, as depicted in your image. And to be fair, I've never encountered an _issue_ either. This is more of a confusion thing. I don't understand why or how there's two, which one does what, and how to avoid this predicament in the future. I know I can check everything in, delete both directories, get latest, and everything is resolved. Checking everything in might not always be able to be done though, so it would be helpful to know what's going on.